# Calling a function from another class in Swift

Tags: swift

I have two classes, Bug and Test. I want to call the bugForName function from the Test class but I get this error:

> "Cannot invoke 'bugForName' with an argument list of type '(String)'

```
import UIKit

class Bug {

    func bugForName(name: String) -> String {
        return "This bug: \(name)"
    }
}

class Test {

    func whatBug() {
        let bugName = "Roach"

        println(Bug.bugForName(bugName))
    }
}
```

[image: Autocomplete]

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Swift?

Comment: You need to read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to call the method from `Bug.Type`, instead of an instance of bug.  You have a couple of options, the first is to make it a class function like so:

```
class Bug {
    class func bugForName(name: String) -> String {
        return "This bug: \(name)"
    }
}
```

The other option is to create an instance of `Bug` before sending the message:

```
class Test {
    func whatBug() {
        let bugName = "Roach"
        let bug = Bug()
        println(bug.bugForName(bugName))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `bugForName()` is a function on an **instance** of class `Bug`.  Invoke it with:

```
Bug().bugForName(bugName))
```

If you intend `bugForName()` to be a class function, declare it as `class func`.